# Snakemake: rule generate strange results

Tags: snakemake

I create this rule:

```
rule picard_addRG2:
    input:
        "mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}.dedup.bam"
    output:
        "mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}_rg.dedup.bam"
    params:
        sample_idi = config['samples'],
        library = "library00"

    shell:
        """picard  AddOrReplaceReadGroups I={input} O={output}  RGID={params.sample_id}  RGLB={params.library} RGPL=illumina  RGPU=unit1 RGSM=20 RGPU=MP"""
```

I  add o Snakemake  file this rule:

```
expand("mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}_rg.dedup.bam",sample=config['samples'])
```

I found this strange result on another rule:

```
snakemake --configfile exome.yaml -np 
InputFunctionException in line 17 of /illumina/runs/FASTQ/test_play/rules/samfiles.rules:
KeyError: '445_rg'
Wildcards:
sample=445_rg
```

What I did wrong?

If I  change the rule in this way works perfectly:

```
rule picard_addRG2:
    input:
        "mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}.dedup.bam"
    output:
        "mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}.dedup_rg.bam"
    params:
        sample_id = config['samples'],
        library = "library00"

    shell:
        """picard  AddOrReplaceReadGroups I={input} O={output}  RGID={params.sample_id}  RGLB={params.library} RGPL=illumina  RGPU=unit1 RGSM=20 RGPU=MP"""
```

Comment: Since "samfiles.rules" is throwing the error, would you be able to post the code for this rule as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works perfectly with the second way to write the output, I would suggest to use this one. What's happening is the following:

since in your rule picard the input is:
`"mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}.dedup.bam"`
you must have a rule that creates this file as output.
and in your rule picard the output is:
`"mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}_rg.dedup.bam"`

So when you ask in your expand:
`"mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}_rg.dedup.bam"`
snakemake does not know if it has to use your rule picard with `sample` as the wildcard or your other rule with `sample_rg` as the wildcard since they both end and begin with the same pattern.

To resume: try not to use two outputs with a wildcard that can be expanded. Here both you outputs:
`"mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}.dedup.bam"`
`"mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}_rg.dedup.bam"`
begin and end with exactly the same pattern.

When you use:
`"mapped_reads/merged_samples/{sample}.dedup_rg.bam"`
as output, the wildcard cannot be expanded!